# Улучшить код крестиков-ноликов

Tags: javascript, ооп, инспекция-кода

Решил втянуться в ООП, написал простейшие крестики-нолики, но с отсутствием опыта в этой области не знаю, что сделал не так, и как это улучшить. Надеюсь на вашу инспекцию ! ;)

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.game = document.getElementById("game")
    this.gameBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("game_block")
    this.winnerDOM = document.getElementById("win")
    this.btnReset = document.getElementById("btn-reset")
    this.cloneGameBlock = new Array(this.gameBlock.length)
    this.current = 0
  }

  calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = lines[i]
      if (
        squares[a] &&
        squares[a] === squares[b] &&
        squares[a] === squares[c]
      ) {
        return squares[a]
      }
    }

    return null
  }

  cloneAnArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cloneGameBlock.length; i++) {
      this.cloneGameBlock[i] = this.gameBlock[i].innerHTML
    }
  }

  winnerDom() {
    if (this.calculateWinner(this.cloneGameBlock)) {
      this.winnerDOM.style.display = "block"
      this.winnerDOM.innerHTML = `Победитель: ${this.calculateWinner(this.cloneGameBlock)}`
    }
  }

  resetGame() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.gameBlock.length; i++) {
      this.gameBlock[i].innerHTML = ""
      this.cloneGameBlock[i] = ""
    }
    this.winnerDOM.innerHTML = ""
    this.current = 0
  }

  addCymeriad(index) {
    if (!this.calculateWinner(this.cloneGameBlock)) {
      if (!this.gameBlock[index].innerHTML) {
        this.current++
          this.current % 2 ?
          (this.gameBlock[index].innerHTML = "X") :
          (this.gameBlock[index].innerHTML = "0")
      }
      this.cloneAnArray()
    }
    this.winnerDom()
  }
}

const game = new Game()

const {
  gameBlock,
  btnReset
} = game

for (let i = 0; i < gameBlock.length; i++) {
  gameBlock[i].addEventListener("click", () => game.addCymeriad(i))
}

btnReset.addEventListener("click", () => game.resetGame())
```

```css
#game {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.game_block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  transition: .4s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.game_block:hover {
  background: rgb(241, 238, 238);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#win {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
  <div class="game_block"></div>
</div>
<h2 id='win'></h2>
<div class="flex flex-center">
  <button id='btn-reset'>Начать заново</button>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь разметку, к которой этот код применяется

Comment: почему кнопки хранятся внутри, а обработчики им присваиваются снаружи?

Comment: в чем заключается ООП в приведенном коде?

Comment: 2) А куда мне их вешать ?
3) Я только сегодня с ООП познакомился, ранее писал только на React, для этого и задал вопрос: что делаю не так?

Comment: не куда, а где. Вопрос был про место навешивания обработчиков, а не на какие элементы его навешивать

Comment: Разве я имел ввиду на какие элементы необходимо вешать?

Comment: _Разве я имел ввиду на какие элементы необходимо вешать?_ я понял вопрос _А куда мне их вешать?_ именно так.

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему вы так поняли. Если вы хотите продолжать писать придирки, то хватит, этого не нужно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79997/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: Я офигеваю от таких вопросителей.  Поддержу @Grundy - я так же понял как и он.....

Comment: @Дмытрык , спасибо вам, ваш комментарий оказался очень полезным.

Comment: Создай метод в который перенеси обработчики событий. Если пишешь класс, то пиши внутри всё. Не выноси, как вынес ты в наружу.